# Maven update dependency versions by groupId

Tags: java, maven, maven-versions-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project.

```
MyProject
├── ModuleA
│   ├── ...
│   └── pom.xml
├── ModuleB
│   ├── ...
│   └── pom.xml
├── ...
└── pom.xml
```

I want to specify a groupId (`com.myCompany.myProject`), and find and update the dependencies that fall into that groupId in all modules (something similar to `npm outdated` and `npm update` by `scope` in JS/NPM world).

Also, I prefer to run these commands using CLI (instead of hardcoding in pom.xml) because the groupId will be determined by a script dynamically.

How can I achieve this with maven?

Comment: what do you mean by "update the dedendencies" ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`versions:use-latest-versions -Dincludes=com.myCompany.myProject:*:*:*:*`

?

Answer (score 0):

You increment the minor version like this:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0 versions:commit
```

or with fixed number of version:

```
mvn  build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=1.13.7.15 versions:commit
```